# Iterating over a dataframe, trying to print a comment for a row that satisfies a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have used pdf-link-checker to produce a 'report.csv' file which details various links and their functionality. I've loaded this CSV to a dataframe using pandas and want to print a specific comment depending on if the link is functional ('NaN') or not in the 'request_error' column.

The issue is that all the links are functional so it should print 'No action required' but it ends up printing 'Mandatory' instead (which would indicate a link is non-functional).[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYUba.png)

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('report.csv', delimiter=';')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if row['request_error'] == 'NaN': 
      print('No actions required')
  else: print('Mandatory')
```

I'm just wondering why it's not printing the correct comment?

Any help is much appreciated.

I've tried iterating using df.itertuples and that didn't work either. I am expecting the output for this print to be: 'No action required' for all 7 links instead of 'Mandatory'.

Comment: You can try using `row['request_error'].isna()`. More info on [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you get **NaN** values, those values are either **np.nan** or **math.nan**. For further reading see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html). So you have to change your condition to something like the following:

```
if row['request_error'] is np.nan: 
      print('No actions required')
else: print('Mandatory')
```

Consider using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) instead of a for loop. It is more efficient.

```
df['request_error'].apply(lambda x: print('No actions required') if x is np.nan else print('Mandatory'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried running the apply function but it still gave me 'Mandatory' instead of the desired 'No actions required' even after setting the condition of ``` x is np.nan```. I tried with math.na as well as pandas.isna and it still didn't work.

I believe there is something wrong with the actual csv file itself as it seems like no matter what condition i set (even for other columns) the loop or apply functions do not recognise the specific condition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PARAK's answer above I did some digging into the specific na parameters within the pandas.read_csv. Nothing seemed to work, but I set na_filter=False and it worked!

I did this with the for loop though, but I'm pretty sure it's an easy application for the apply function.